# Integration of business logic in SharePoint

Tags: power-automate, azure, sharepoint-integration

I am currently designing a resource booking system for rooms.

My plan is:

I have a custom list with all the rooms.

Whenever a new room is added, a script creates an Outlook calendar for it.

This Outlook calendar is then integrated via a link field, so users can click and book it.

I don't want to allow users to book a room while someone else has already booked it, I already achieved that via a field validation formula in Outlook, but also a more sophisticated script:

The script is going to check if the person booking has booked the room for more than 30 days in the last 2 months. If it detects this, it will inform the user that he can't book, but he can request it (standard approval request, as you can integrate in SharePoint)

My problem is:

I am developing a solution for the first time in SharePoint, and I can't find the right option for myself.

I really like these PowerAutomate flows, but I cannot create an Outlook calendar there (I need to get the premium version to make HTTPS calls to the Outlook API)

I would buy the premium version, but the pricing is really obscure. It says that it's 15 dollars a month for personal use, with unlimited flows. But I can also book 5 flows for 500 dollars a month.

I don't think that personal use applies, because every sane organization would simply create one account that handles all the flows, and since its unlimited I can basically automate everything for just 15 dollars a month.

And if the second case applies, I would need to pay thousands of dollars. There are about 300 rooms, each one needs an own calendar. Each calendar needs a flow because I cant trigger one flow from multiple triggers (Afaik).

So I would pay about 30k a month? That would not make any sense.

I am currently thinking about implementing this via Webhooks into a Azure Function, but keeping it all within SharePoint and PowerAutomate would make things a lot easier.

What am I missing? Whats the secret ingredient right here :D

Thanks alot in advance, I am quite helpless with SharePoint and all its features.

Comment: I can't see why you'd need 300 flows. You only have one list. Adding a new item to the list is the trigger. You'd use variables to configure your http request.

Comment: Because I have 300 calendars, one for each room. And afaik I can only add a flow to one object (one flow per calendar)